# dark souls equivalent keys xbox-> pc

Tags: dark-souls

I'm playing the pc-version of dark souls, does anybody knows what is the equivalent of "rs" for the pc-keyboard? thanks

Sorry, I already saw the other answers, but I couldn't find the key "rs" and his equivalent for pc...perhaps I'm a bit thick :-( .....

Comment: You should look into DS mousefix if you want to play with a keyboard..

Comment: sorry again... what means "DS mousefix" ??

Comment: @franco1206 google it.